# How to set docker image name in docker compose file from user input?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, docker-image

When upping docker-compose file I want to set the service image from user input. if there was not any tag in the input image I want to set latest tag. How to do this?

For example, i have this docker-compose file-

```yaml
    version: '3.7'

    services:
         ping:
           container_name: svc_name
           image: image_name:tag_name
           ports:
             - 8080:8080
           command: serve
           environment:
             - CONSUL_URL=consul_dev:8500
             - CONSUL_PATH=ping
           tty: true
```

Here I want to set `image_name:tag_name` from user input when building the compose file. The must-have more service so I have to specify on which service I am taking the input image.

Comment: @abu-fahrad You have to be much more specific than that. What do you mean by user input? From where? A frontend or a backend? What is the application? How many users will you have? It's definitely a very bad idea to just let users write directly into a compose file without any checks.

Comment: Yeah, it's from BE.  I'm creating a makefile where I want to specify this image name as well as image tag_name.

Comment: Actually, this is a microservice compose file. if I change a service then for build-up I don't want to change manually in compose file. I just want to change in makefile script.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to solve that it issue was:

```sh
read -p "Please enter the PING service image name: " ping_image_name

if [ -z "${ping_image_name}" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

read -p "Please enter the OTHER service image name: " other_image_name

if [ -z "${other_image_name}" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

ping_image_name="${ping_image_name-default_ping_image_name}" \
other_image_name="${other_image_name-default_other_image_name}" \
docker-compose build ...command arguments...
```

```yaml
    version: '3.7'

    services:
         ping:
           container_name: svc_name
           image: ${ping_image_name}
           ports:
             - 8080:8080
           command: serve
           environment:
             - CONSUL_URL=consul_dev:8500
             - CONSUL_PATH=ping
           tty: true

         other:
           container_name: svc_name
           image: ${ping_image_name}
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio. 
But how you can specify the image_name for which service? There have multiple services. 
I just want to up the docker-compose file not build.

Comment: Hi, are you asking a new question? It seems different from your first one which I answered. If so, please accept , then open a second one in order to get further information. Regards.

Comment: It's ok for your ans. But maybe you missed my last line of the question. Please read the last line of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I check it again. :)

Comment: I edited it. Please check again my solution.